# How to solve this first order ODE right

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Here is ODE of first order:

$$ y'=- \frac{x^2}{y^3} $$
with $y(0)=1 , y(0)=-1 $

Can my method be the separation method? If I use it, it doesn't work out:

$ \frac{dy}{dx}= -x^2 \frac{1}{y^3} $
$ \leftrightarrow y^3 dy = -x^2 dx $

By integration I get:

$$ \int y^3 dx = \int -x^2 dx $$
$$ \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4} y^4+c = - \frac{1}{3} x^3+c $$
$$ \leftrightarrow y= \mp \sqrt[4]{ - \frac{4}{3} x^3 +c } $$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: why is it wrong?

Comment: Why do you assume you're incorrect? Find $y'$ and find $-x^2/y^3$. They match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If $y\not=0$ then
$$y'=- \frac{x^2}{y^3}\leftrightarrow \int y^3 dy = \int -x^2 dx \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4} y^4= - \frac{1}{3} x^3+c  \leftrightarrow y= \pm \sqrt[4]{ - \frac{4}{3} x^3 +c }. $$
Now for $y(0)=1$, we get
$$ y(x)= \color{blue}{+}\sqrt[4]{1 - \frac{4}{3} x^3},$$
whereas for $y(0)=-1$ we find
$$ y(x)= \color{blue}{-}\sqrt[4]{1 - \frac{4}{3} x^3}.$$
Both solutions, which are symmetric with respect to the line $y=0$, are defined in the half-line $(-\infty,(3/4)^{1/3})$.